# "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" while Insert

Tags: mysql, select, insert, subquery

I have a MySQL Database and wanted to insert some Data. In my DB there are two tables with the name `tx_yes_cantons` and `tx_yes_areas`.

In the cantons table i want to have the ID (in my case uid) from an area. Now when i try this:

```
INSERT INTO `tx_yes_cantons` (tx_yes_areas_uid, cantonname, code)
    VALUES (
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Genferseeregion'), 'Genf', 'ge'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Mittelland'), 'Freiburg', 'fr'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Nordwestschweiz'), 'Basel-Stadt', 'bs'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Zentralschweiz'), 'Obwalden', 'ow'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Tessin'), 'Tessin', 'ti'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Zürich'), 'Zürich', 'zh'),
        ((SELECT `uid` FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` Like 'Ostschweiz'), 'Schaffhausen', 'sh');
```

I get the error in the title. Why? i don't see anything wrong.. :S

Comment: Try to execute all select query. Some Query may return more than one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some query returns more than one row. If you need to insert all rows in your `tx_yes_cantons` table, you probably need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tx_yes_cantons` (tx_yes_areas_uid, cantonname, code)
SELECT `uid`, 'Genf', 'ge'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Genferseeregion'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Freiburg', 'fr'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Mittelland'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Basel-Stadt', 'bs'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Nordwestschweiz'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Obwalden', 'ow'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Zentralschweiz'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Tessin', 'ti'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Tessin'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Zürich', 'zh'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Zürich'
UNION ALL
SELECT `uid`, 'Schaffhausen', 'sh'
FROM `tx_yes_areas` WHERE `areaname` = 'Ostschweiz'
```

or also:

```
INSERT INTO `tx_yes_cantons` (tx_yes_areas_uid, cantonname, code)
SELECT tx_yes_areas.uid, codes.cantonname, codes.code
FROM
  tx_yes_areas INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'Genferseeregion' areaname, 'Genf' cantonname, 'ge' code
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mittelland', 'Freiburg', 'fr'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Nordwestschweiz', 'Basel-Stadt', 'bs'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Zentralschweiz', 'Obwalden', 'ow'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Tessin', 'Tessin', 'ti'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Zürich', 'Zürich', 'zh'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Ostschweiz', 'Schaffhausen', 'sh') codes
  ON tx_yes_areas.areaname = codes.areaname
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But i've deleted the entries that were redundant now. Anyway i have a question. What does the Select do instead of VALUES ?

Comment: @AgashThamo. if you don't want reduntant rows, you could modify first query using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, or using `SELECT DISTINCT tx_yes_areas...` on the second one, using VALUES you can only insert one row at a time

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following query in the database:

```
select areaname, count(*) from tx_yes_areas group by (areaname) having count(*)>1;
```

All the results returned will show possible duplicates, in case, any of the areaname is similar to one in the insert query, then try deleting the redundant entries from tx_yes_areas table.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that i don't have redunant entrys. But i had. My false. I deleted the entrys and it worked! :D